# Load template from script level using HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile call via a Google Apps Script library

Tags: google-apps-script

I have the following function in a library called lib.

```
var Template =
    {      
      GetContents: function (templateName)
      {
        var templateContents;

        try 
         {
          templateContents = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(templateName).getContent();
         }
        catch (e)
        {
          return undefined;
        }

        return templateContents;
      },

     };
```

I would like to call this function from a script that uses the library, like so:

```
templateContents = lib.Template.GetContents('htmltemplate');
```

However, when I do this it does not return 'htmltemplate' from the script level - it returns 'htmltemplate' from the library level instead. I Would like to retrieve the contents of 'htmltemplate' from the script level, not the library level, how can I get the desired result?

Comment: May be you could use "createHtmlOutput(html)" or "createHtmlOutput(blob)" with passing the content to the lib instead of "createHtmlOutputFromFile". But i don't think that's a good practice because of the volume of data to transfer each time... Not sure using a library for this purpose is a good idea !

Comment: @tristan When you use libraries, they are loaded into the execution instance, so there is no extra "transfer" to some other server--the only transfer was an extra read from the other script project to create the library and its closure. That read is performed on every new script invocation. @op if you need to use a library method to access host-specific resources you need to provide the specific getter/resource. You can see examples of this in other questions re: `PropertiesService` and `CacheService`

Comment: @tehhowch : Many thanks ! The mechanism of lib was not clear to me on this point, and i thought it was like two independant apps communicating together...

Comment: @tehhowch Thanks for the feedback. I've been looking in to the PropertiesService and CacheService but I'm not sure exactly what I need to do with them. Is there any chance you know of a specific question / example that would be useful to me?